# bash script exits with zero status even after kill signal

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, kill, exitstatus

I keep getting zero status even after interrupting the script.

**The first script**

```
#!/bin/bash

## call the backup script
/usr/local/bin/backup 2>&1 >/dev/null
echo $?
```

**backup**

```
#!/bin/bash

exitscript() {
 rm -f $LOCKFILE

 echo "Script Status: $1 | tee -a ${LOG}"
 echo "> End Date: $(date +'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')" | tee -a ${LOG}
 exit $1
}

######START#######
trap "exitscript 1" 1 2 23 24 25

rsync ${args} ${src} ${dest} | tee -a ${RSYNC_LOG}
retcode=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
if [[ ${retcode} -ne 0 ]]; then
  exitcode=1
fi

exitscript ${exitcode:-0}
```

When the First Script is run, it returns exit status of 0 although i have tried to kill the backup script before it ends (for that i have created a very large size file so that rsync takes time to copy the file and i get the time to kill the script before it ends)

```
ps -ef | grep -i backup
kill $PID
```

Another thing is that even after killing the backup script, rsync still runs. I would like for rsync to stop once the script is being killed and my first script to return the status code of zero.
Much appreciation for any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the missing quote in `echo "Script Status: $1 | tee -a ${LOG}` is not relevant to the question.
When you want a function to handle the trap, you need to export that function.
And when you want to kill children, you should add these in your trap-function.

I tested these adjustments with a `sleep` command, it should work for `rsync` too.

```
#!/bin/bash

exitscript() {
 echo "Script Status: $1"
 (( $pleasekill > 0 )) && kill ${pleasekill}
 echo "> End Date: $(date +'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')"
 exit $1
}

# Export the function exitscript
export exitscript

######START#######
pleasekill=0
trap "exitscript 1" 1 2 23 24 25
# Start I/O-friendly rsync function
sleep 30 &
pleasekill=$!
wait

exitscript 2
```

When you test this with the first script, use `^C` or `kill -1 pid_of_backup`.

Comment: with my Rsync command i sometimes want to see the output on the screen when user uses verbose and at the same save it to the logfile. By sending it to the background i won't be able to that would i? Is there any other way to get the PID of the process or any get around solution to solve both cases? Thanks

Comment: Try something with `ps -ef`, `pgrep` or `pkill`.